# NodeJS stream response to prevent out of memory errors

Tags: node.js, memory-management, stream, zlib

i have the following code:

```
 response.writeHead(200 , {
   'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
   'Content-encoding': 'gzip',
   "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename="+getFileName()
});

var zlib = require("zlib");
var data = getData(); //some arbitrary data from a method
var outputStr = "";
var header = "some header";
var footer = "some footer";

outputStr+= header;

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  outputStr+= data[i].utils.generateString(); //xml parser and various whatnots resulting in a string
}

outputStr+= footer;

zlib.gzip(outputStr, function(err, result) {
  response.end(result); //works on small strings
})
```

sometimes, my string length exceeds the 512mb limit (which is fine), thus, on a 32 bit system, so I'll get:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I've been reading about streams, however all the examples talk abour reading files, rather then generated values.

How can i create a stream and push the data into it during iteration (my loop) instead of writing it all inside a string and pushing it as a response.

It's important that the output will invoke a file download, the same as it does today, along with the gzip support (which is asynchronous so, it needs to be taken into consideration)

Comment: You'll have to ditch the `zlib.gzip` convenience function and create a stream with `createGzip` and send your data chunks to it (and ideally pipe its output to your response stream in chunks).

Comment: chinks as in passing a 'transfer-coding: chunked' header?
could you perhaps provide an example (or point me to one) involving createGzip?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a streaming response, so you create the Gzip stream outside of the convenience functions.

Example:

```
var zlib=require('zlib');
var fs=require('fs');

var gz=zlib.createGzip();
var res=fs.createWriteStream('./test.gz');

gz.pipe(res);

var data=['hi','test','data'];
var i;
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    gz.write(data[i]);
}
gz.end();  // this will implicitly call 'res.end()' by default
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, however, i don't want to write anything into a file: I'd like to push the data to the user.

Comment: It's an example.  In your case, you already have a response stream via the web request.  I didn't feel like writing up a full http example so I used a file as the target instead.  Remember, in node -- streams are streams.  Whether it's the console, a zip stream, a network connection, a file... you can do the same things (mostly) with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If this data code genrates a discrete sctring, you should be able to use response.write inside your loop to achieve this.

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  response.write(data[i].utils.generateString());
}
```